# c# download weird behavior

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, tableau-api

So I'm trying to download files from internet using `C#`, and there are two kinds of files: `.twb` and `.twbx`, where `.twbx` is a zip containing a `.twb` and two other folders. My download program works fine when downloading `.twb` files, but when I download the `.twbx`, I always end up with a completely different file - same name, but very different in size and content. Any idea why this might happen?

---

Here's the code for downloading:

```
request = setUpRequest(dLink);

((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = true;
((HttpWebRequest)request).Host = host;
((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
((HttpWebRequest)request).Referer = referer;
((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate,sdch";
((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers["X-CSRF-Token"] = CSRF_TOKEN;
((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers["X-Prototype-Version"] = "1.7_rc3";
((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
((HttpWebRequest)request).Headers["Origin"] = origin;

response = getResponse(request);
Stream resp = response.GetResponseStream();

if ((response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip")))
{
    resp = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(resp, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);
}
else if ((response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate")))
{
    resp = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(resp, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);
}
String buffer = new StreamReader(resp, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();

String filename = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
filename = Regex.Match(filename, "\".*\"").Value;
filename = filename.Substring(1, filename.Length - 2);
//Console.WriteLine("Writing content to {0}...", filename);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(directory + filename, buffer);
resp.Close();
resp.Dispose();
```

---

and here is `setUpRequest()` in case you are curious:

```
    private static WebRequest setUpRequest(String url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        return request;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't decode a binary content to text because that will break the binary. Just copy the raw bytes from your input stream to the `FileStream`:

```
String filename = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
filename = Regex.Match(filename, "\".*\"").Value;
filename = filename.Substring(1, filename.Length - 2);
using (FileStream target = new FileStream(directory + filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
     resp.CopyTo(target);
resp.Close();
resp.Dispose();
```